# Core Data model design for charting data

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am sorry for the verbose explanation, I do however feel it is necessary for me to explain the details so that I can gain help in the best way to create the correct core data model to fulfill my requirements.

I am simply trying to find out the best way to create my data model so that I can achieve the below in a quick efficient fashion, which is not currently possible with my current MySQL setup. I am using MySQL to return all the values from the server, but now wish to use CoreData to cache this data, and only download the new dated data.

I have a database that stores datasets like this:

```
{
    "Agent_Id" = 32;
    "Order_FinalisedDate" = "2014-05-17 03:39:54";
    "Order_Id" = 2596;
    "Order_ReferenceNumber" = "Pavan/0905/016";
    "PieChart_Id" = 13585;
    "PieChart_QuantityATOP" = 150;
    "PieChart_TotalAmount" = 52500;
    "Product_Id" = 20;
}
```

I have 13,585 of these data sets flying in from the server every time I load the viewController. It takes over 1 and a half minutes to process the data retrieved from the server. This is highly inefficient and I seek to create a Core Data model to help me with the processes to cut down significantly on time.

This is the current process that takes place without Core Data

1. I am only interested in the last 12 rolling months just like how banks return your accounts for the last 12 months for example. So I get a live dynamic array from the server in JSON format, copying them nicely over to its custom `BankDateDataModel` data model in an array called `monthsChartDataDictionary` which stores the data in this format `yyyy-MM`.
2. I then go through all the sales and grab and categorise them if it has a date that can be associated to a matching date in the `monthsChartDataDictionary` array.

   ```
   //Go through each data set
   for(id key in JSONDictionary){
       //First lets store each data set which we will use for another process.
       PieChartSliceDataModel *pcs = [[PieChartSliceDataModel alloc] initWithJSONData:key];
       [allPieChartDataArray addObject:pcs];

       /**
           Check to see if we have a date entry in the format of `yyyy-MM`
           If there is a 
       */

       if([monthsChartDataDictionary objectForKey:pcs.PCS_StringOrderFinalisedDate]){
           [[monthsChartDataDictionary objectForKey:pcs.PCS_StringOrderFinalisedDate] addObject:pcs];
       }
   }
   ```

   And this is essentially what is created - monthsChartDataDictionary. a Dictionary which has its keys in the format of `yyyy-MM` and an array of data sets in their associated keys.

   ```
   {   //An nsdictionary holding over 13,500 elements.
       "2013-05"=(..,..,..);
       "2013-06"=(..,..,..);
       "2013-07"=(etc);
       "2013-08"=();
       "2013-09"=();
       "2013-10"=();
       "2013-11"=();
       "2013-12"=();
       "2014-01"=();
       "2014-02"=();
       "2014-03"=();
       "2014-04"=();
       "2014-05"=();
   }
   ```
3. A for loop is then run to achieve two things at once, see a) and b) below:

   a)  For each month in the monthsChartDataDictionary dictionary, I get the total sales for that month by tallying the `PieChart_TotalAmount` for each dataset. This is used to create a line chart showing total sales across the year. [image]

   b) A new dictionary is made - finalPieChartData where each key is in the format of `yyyy-MM` and the values stored are an array of products that show the total sale values for each product.  This is so that a pie chart can be made showing sales across products **within any given month**. Where `12sp B - 250` is the name of a product. [image]

How can I best represent all of this in a core data model?

Im thinking if theres a way to store all the required data, with total sales values too, and seperate sales across products for given months... all stored in core data... or if its best to make these calculations when they are retured from the core data database, im guessing this will only cause more delay.

I have this so far:

[image]

My logic in creating this was based on the following thoughts:

1. That I could have a database that stores all the individual datasets
2. Another table that stores the total monthly sales for the line charts, so I dont have to keep performing the calculation, unless ofcourse I need to update sales figures for the latest month as I obtain new sales that are still taking place in the same current month.
3. And along with that montly sale core data model, there would be an array of pie chart slices that represent the total sale for each product id within any particular month. This will mean that I dont have to keep processing the calculations again and again.

Is this correct? Is there an efficient way to store everything?

### Update 1: updated the proposed core data model in an attempt to make things more efficient once implemented into the application

[image]

Comment: This is not an opinionated question. I am looking for a good approach to the core data model design.

Comment: You are specifically interested in optimizing the model to make the UI responsive and the memory footprint of the app minimal, right?  Because you mention a slow fetch but do not mention the core data stack used for that... whether you create a temporary context, and whether it's using parent-child, etc.  But the core data stack and background fetching is separate from this question, right?

Comment: Hey @stevesliva, I am not using a core data stack atm. What takes a long time is what I mentioned in step 1. processing the `json` data into an `nsdictionary`, another part that takes a very long time is step 2 where I create all the pie chart data. So I am specifically asking for the best way to structure the data model so that all the data is already processed ready to be retrieved with all the pre-calculated values since they would be saved into the data store like that, and then only need to be presented. Cont.

Comment: Cont. Hence why im trying to find the best wy to store all the required data so that when I retrieve the data, I dont need to do any processing.

Comment: @stevesliva, anyone?!

Comment: I think the issue is that there's no right answer.  You're basically asking whether the calculations should be view-only, or backed in the model.  I think that if you put the derived calculation results in the model, you create the headache of having dependent keypaths.  So I wouldn't....  And looking at your #2, and #3... caching those calculations seems like a good idea.  Sticking them in the persistent store, maybe not.

Comment: @stevesliva How do you cache calculations while not sticking them in the persistent store? I thought by having these data sets stored in the persistent store it would a) save me from fetching over 13 thousand records everytime the user needs to display the yearly sales - line chart, and monthly product sales - pie chart, where I would only update the persistent store when new sales are present. b) saving the calculations would save calculation times too. What are your thought processes for what you stated? Thanks for commenting

Comment: @stevesliva Hey, if you could have a look at my last comment pls.

Comment: When you get the data from the server can you select a time period?

Comment: @68cherries, I can. What I've been thinking that during first mapping of the app database, it would take time, but then thereafter, I would only need to retrieve the new data based on when the last update was done, and that time would need to be sent to the server so that it returns the records thereafter, and once retrieved the last update time variable should be updated. Now Im trying to figure out how to create the data model for it all. If someone can actually read the post properly, and note down everything that goes on to make this work, and then correct the model, I'll increase bounty.

Comment: Is there any reason why you will not do the pie charts and all computations in the server and then just allow the mobile device access to the rendered page?  Just want to know. Core data may be efficient if the downloaded data can be used on a semi permanent basis - meaning you only purge the data once a month (13th month data) and take in new data (new month data) so you definitely reduce the data download to 1/12th the volume. ... I don't quite get the way you constructed your core data model - Are you trying to construct MTD and YTD tables?

Comment: What are the Piechart fields?

Comment: @Paulo, the data needs to be live, I.e if a customer makes an order right now, the higher management should be able to see the updated sales the very second later.

Comment: @Paulo, please see the post for an updated proprosed coredata model in my attempt to make things more efficient once I implement it into the app.

Comment: Curious why you wouldn't do all the heavy lifting at the server and only return the totals you need to display the graph? That sort of aggregation and calculation is exactly the sort of thing that servers excel at and mobile devices do not.

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons how would I do these calculations on the server? Do I have to keep some sort of table that stores the current total for each month of the year, and every time a new sale is made, tally that into that table's month row? Also I still need the data to be sent over since more charts will need to be made based on the data given from the server. I have to create charts for individual customers too and more, and that would be arranged differently, it gets crazy. lol I heard that calculations shouldnt be stored on the database if they can be calculated, but besides the point)

Comment: @MichaelG.Emmons I heard that calculations shouldnt be stored on the DB if they can be calculated, but besides the point). How would I do these calculations on the server? Do I have to keep some sort of table that stores the current total for each month of the year, and every time a new sale is made, tally that into that table's month row? Also I still need the data to be sent over since more charts will need to be made based on the data given from the server. I have to create charts for individual customers too and more, and that would be arranged differently, it gets crazy. lol. Continued

Comment: So I figured, send each sale to the device, and store it locally, and update when new data is available. So I'm trying to come up with an efficient coredata model for those reasons. Once the calculations are done on the device, with the persistent store storing the calculations too, only new calculations would be done thereafter. So I think it will be fine.

Comment: @Pavan you need server-side aggregation for your data if you have that much of it.

Comment: @Pavan You need an Oracle or SQL developer to answer those questions. You can get totals and such via sql queries, but that goes well beyond the scope of this question. Trying to do this stuff on a mobile device is never going to be performant.

Comment: @pavan, The charts can be done in the server. There maybe value in using Local Data (Core Data) to allow offline usage, but if as you say the data needs to be live - just do everything in the server. There are packages and SDKs available for server side pie chart generation, it should come with rudimentary data handling routines, if this is not enough look into server side OLAP packages. moving the data to mobile is bad design, specially if you are just going to discard them afterwards.

Comment: Consider Olap but otherwise scratch my last comment (I didn't read the rest of the posts). I understand that you are trying to build MTD and YTD tables - that is ok, I still don't understand what those piechart fields are - put the update date in the MTD and YTD tables it does not need to be a stand alone. also you is there value in putting in an Agent and product table so you can display detailed info about the agent and product. Core data and SQL tables should have similar structures the only diff is the absence of foreign keys, the core data relationship are pointers.

Comment: I still don't understand what and why the pie chart fields are inside your order table.

Comment: @Paulo In update 1: The first entity holds the data required for the year graph. The second entity holds the data required to produce the seperate monthly pie charts which display a tally of quantity sold for a set of products put nicely in a pie chart, it shows product contribution in sales for that particular month. And the third entity are the details for each sale which is how the other entities get their total values through calculations.

Comment: I got that Month to date (MTD) tabulations and Year to date (YTD). Seems like a regular Order entry system except the PieChartID throws me off - The piechart QTYATOP is just  qty and and the piechart total amount is just the order total sales  I presume it is only for the specific order. It will be clearer if you list the details of the relationship - M-M O-M M-O.  ...  You also need to replicate Qty and Amount in the MTD and YTD fields.

Comment: The way I see it you should create a MTD and YTD table server side. these tables should be tabulated while the order is being made (it can also be batch - after end of day). your app only needs the MTD data to generate your reports not the individual orders.

Answer (score 0):

NSDateFormatter is very harmful for the performance. If you are using it in your 1st during mapping you should minimize it's allocations. You can provide code snippet of 1st step if you wan't

Also you can use in xcode product-profile-time profiler. It can help you to track low performance operations.

As for working with web-services and core data take a look an [restKit](https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit)

Also you might peace of advice under this  links from raywenderlich on working with web services and core data [part 1](http://www.raywenderlich.com/15916/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-1) [part 2](http://www.raywenderlich.com/17927/how-to-synchronize-core-data-with-a-web-service-part-2)

Comment: Hi, thank you for posting. I am the one who create the web service, im familiar with communicating with a restful server too. I know where the slow processes are taking place. I am not using `NSDateFormatters` yet. Please read my post again and carefully too. The reason it takes forever is that in the first step, I am allocating over 13,000 objects and storing it in an array, and then making calculations on that array to create my pie chart data and my line graph data. I seperate the data so that the objects show in the right month categories and correct pie charts. cont.

Comment: I am asking for you to make a note on: the dataset `keys`, and how I use the sales data (over 13,000 of them) to create the graphs that I need, but to then have an efficient data model that stores these values; calculated values for each month; and pie chart values too so that I don't need to keep iterating through every data set just to calculate the graph data that I need everytime I need to display graphs. If you could look through the data model once youve made a note of the dataset and understood how it all is calculated, then explaining the right way to store everything would be great.

Comment: @Pavan thank you for clarifiing. Can you add code snippet of 1st step. Or if it is a big chunk of code add  part which is the most critical on yours opinion

Comment: Lol, believe me its not going to be helpful for you as it does not even relate to the question. It also takes less than a milli second to do. All it does is receive an array consisting of 12 elements (which are the last 12 months string dates from today) stored in a dictionary variable called `monthsChartDataDictionary`. Have a look in step 2 of what the dictionary looks like. The code fragment is very small. It's actually very trivial. Then it moves straight away to step 2.

Comment: check my last comment pls, mate.

Comment: @Pavan You can check this link for some tips. I will think about your last comment. Your question is no trivial) And there could several approaches
http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=2160906&WT.mc_id=Author_Roadley_CoreDataMistakes

Answer (score 0):

For an Order Entry system you need a Month to date (MTD) and Year to date (YTD) table in the server side with the following fields: date updated, total sales amount and total quantity of orders. The tables should be updated live with the orders or updated nightly by batch. The app needs only download the MTD data to generate the required sales charts.    There could be some value in creating a local store for the MTD tables but with the reduced amount of data, it may not be necessary.

If filtering is required, consider creation individual tables (MTD) for the required filters instead of trying to tabulate and recompute everything in the app.

Comment: Thank you for posting, however, I do feel that following this method will get very messy on the server side. There has to be the level of flexibility I'd like within my app. Without having to transfer the data again and again depending on the filters selected. It's just not the way to go about it. Thats why we have core data, to allow for local storage. The question again, is available in my post.

Comment: The data transfer is very expensive. Order Entry systems have always been constructed with MTD and YTD tables for the past 30-40 years. Bank accounts are similarly done in the same way.  Its not messy if the tables are updated live (as transactions come in (in the old days these MTD were batched at end of day from the transaction log). If you were not the guy who constructed the order entry system - why don't you ask first, they probably have those tables in place already. If its an off the shelf package, those thing will already be in place.

Comment: If you are worried about the filters - identify them and plug it into the MTD table as separate fields that get totalled into the total amount and total qty. that will solve your complexity issue. You can also do the same thing in the iOS devices, but you need to remember that the same work gets replicated on each device and for me its bad design.